# Using a bash file to print members of a group to a file

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I'm going to be transparent, this is homework but I'm about ready to put a hole in my computer. I've looked around online and either I'm asking the wrong questions or something.

Basically, I'm writing a bash script to create a file, I then need to get a group and print those to that file and it needs to print line by line.

I can create the file easily enough, by using touch

`touch /dir/output.txt`

I believe that the code would be something like

```
for each group member in group length
printf "name,password,group" >> /dir/output.txt
```

So my question is, how do I print the members of a group to that file?

Regards,

Mentally drained student.

Answer (score 0):

To list the members of a group, you'd query the `group` NSS database for the group's name to get the gid and members.

And you'd also need to query the `passwd` (user) database to also check for users with the corresponding gid. Could be with:

```
group_name=somegroup
awk -F: '
  !groups_processed {
    gid[$3] # record gid in gid hash
    split($4, members, ",") # extract members
    for (i in members) users[members[i]] # unique members listed as
                                         # keys of users hash
    next
  }
  $4 in gid {
    users[$1] # also record users with corresponding gid
  }
  END {
    for (i in users) print i
  }' <(getent -- group "$group_name") \
     groups_processed=1 \
     <(getent passwd) | sort
```

Usually, there's only one entry for each group name in the database but on systems with more that one db (like files and ldap), you can sometimes find more¹. Here we're recording the gids of all, which may or may not the best thing to do. Also note that different groups could have the same gid, here we're not including the users listed as members of different groups with same gid.

---

<sup>¹ here on a GNU system, I find that `getent group` alone lists them all, but `getent group thegroupname` only returns one of them</sup>